# SQL to LINQ entities sql query profile isn't expected

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

So I have this query:

```
using (var unitOfWork = this.unitOfWorkFactory.Create(LockType.Read))
{
    var blogRepository = this.repositoryFactory.Create<SpaTest.Domain.Blogging.Blog>(unitOfWork);
    var postRepository = this.repositoryFactory.Create<SpaTest.Domain.Blogging.Post>(unitOfWork);

    var blogs = blogRepository.Retrieve()
        .GroupJoin(
            postRepository.Retrieve(),
            b => b.Id,
            p => p.BlogId,
            (blog, posts) =>
            new Models.Blogging.Blog()
                {
                    Title = blog.Title,
                    Content = blog.Content,
                    DateAdded = blog.DateAdded,
                    Id = blog.Id,
                    PostCount = posts.Count()
                }).Distinct();

    var result = blogs.ToArray();

    return this.Ok(result);
}
```

And I am expecting to get a join statement back because MSDN states that this is the equivalent of a left outer join.

So basically, I'm wanting to get back all the blogs and for each blog the number of posts it has. SQL Profiler is actually showing 2 individual select statements:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Content] AS [Content], 
[Extent1].[BlogId] AS [BlogId], 
[Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
[Extent1].[DateAdded] AS [DateAdded]
FROM [dbo].[Posts] AS [Extent1]

SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Extent1].[Content] AS [Content], 
[Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
[Extent1].[DateAdded] AS [DateAdded]
FROM [dbo].[Blogs] AS [Extent1]
```

So I don't what is going on here.

***EDIT***

The `Retrieve()` implementation:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Retrieves entities from the repository based on the query provided
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="query">
        /// The query to use when matching entities in the repository
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The <see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/> of entities retrieved from the repository
        /// </returns>
        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Retrieve(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> query)
        {
            if (query == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("query", "A query must be specified to use the overloaded Retrieve method.  To retrieve all entities, use Retrieve()");
            }

            return this.unitOfWork.Context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().Where(query);
        }
```

***CONTEXT UPDATE***

So after changing the `using(var unitOfWork....` to `using(var context = new DefaultContext())` I got this sql output:

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Project1].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Project1].[Content] AS [Content], 
[Project1].[DateAdded] AS [DateAdded], 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C2]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
    [Extent1].[Content] AS [Content], 
    [Extent1].[DateAdded] AS [DateAdded], 
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Posts] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[BlogId]) AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Blogs] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Project1]
```

Comment: what does `Retrieve` do?

Comment: Sorry, yeah it returns an `IEnumerable<>` but that is dependent on what the `ObjectContext` returns, so in this instance it is an `IQueryable<>`

Comment: So does it return `IEnumerable<>` or `IQueryable<>`? Because that's pretty important on how your query works.

Comment: see edits, if `IQueryable<>` implements `IEnumerable<>` why does it make so much difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Retrieve` method you are implicitly casting from `IQueryable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` which is the equivalent to calling [AsEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb335435(v=vs.100).aspx) on your query. The consequence of this is your `GroupJoin` call uses the `IEnumerable<T>` implementation (which runs in memory) and not the `IQueryable<T>` one (which runs on the DB).

Given the only thing required to perform an in-memory `GroupJoin` is the records themselves, this explains why only two `SELECT` statements are generated. To force the `GroupJoin` to be performed at the DB end you need to return `IQueryable<T>` from your  `Retrieve` method.

Comment: Okay, so after my `Retrieve()` method I put `AsQueryable<>` and it still had the same effects. Obviously the sql profiler doesn't show anything till you hit the `var result` line.

Comment: So instead of doing that `UnitOfWork` pattern I did a `using(var context = new DefaultContext())` and did the same query. I only got one sql statement this time, so I guess somewhere down the line its not liking the `IEnumerable<>`, I put the SQL in the main post.

Comment: It would appear that somewhere down the line the query is being switched over to `IEnumerable<T>`, as a test could you try doing `blogs.Retrieve().Where(...).AsQueryable().Count()` - if `AsQueryable` works as expected this would generate `COUNT` SQL and no filtering for the `WHERE`.

Comment: I changed the source code in the end to return an `IQueryable<>` from `Retrieve()` and it worked a treat!